# Strange Method of Differentiating $x^2$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

A book by the name of [*Calculus Super Textbook*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0878917810) teaches the following method for differentiating $x^2$ with respect to $x$: Take the equation: $$y=x^2$$ The author reasons that increasing both $x$ and $y$ by a differential amount preserves equality, so: $$y+dy=(x+dx)^2$$
Expanding the right-hand side gives: $$y+dy=x^2+2xdx+dx^2$$ Subtract off the original $y=x^2$: $$dy=2xdx+dx^2$$ The author reasons that an infinitesimal change in $x$ multiplied by an infinitesimal change in $x$ is so small to be effectively zero, so any powers of $dx$ higher than $1$ are dropped: $$dy=2xdx$$ Then, dividing both sides by $dx$: $${dy \over dx}=2x$$ This is nothing like the methods I've been taught for finding a derivative (which I understand to be the limit of the difference quotient), but it at least appears to work for polynomial functions. Is this a valid method that I'm not aware of? If so, how would you use this to differentiate more complex functions like sine and cosine?

Comment: It's a useful way of thinking in many applied contexts. It is the way Leibniz and others explained things. Unfortunately a lot hand-wavy.

Comment: The [exact same question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/441525/86299) was posted a few days ago (are you two in the same class, by any chance?). You should read the [accepted answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/441540/86299) there for a clear explanation.

Comment: It's pretty similar, but I'm not sure if I'd call it the "exact same question"; that one's about the associativity of a particular multiplication, and mine is whether this method is valid. And no, I wasn't in a class with anyone when happened to come across this book.

Answer (score 7):

This is calculus based on differentials, which is different from the limits-based calculus that is prevalent these days.  However, despite what some commenters (and contemporaries of Newton and Leibniz) feel, this is perfectly sound logically.  If you'd like to see some details of how to work with infinitesimals, I recommend [Keislers' Calculus](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html), which he has kindly placed online for free.

Comment: Well, yes and no. Formal work with infinitesimals in the modern sense (as in the Robinson-Keisler approach) does not have $dx^2=0$, this is in fact false. One can formalize this approach (there are even some papers in the Monthly showing how), and call these objects infinitesimals if one wishes, but they are different beasts.

Comment: See for example: Dawn Fisher. *Extending functions to infinitesimals of finite order*, Amer. Math. Monthly, **89 (7)**, (1982), 443–449. [MR0673634 (84f:03058)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=673634).